# Is there a way to disable 'clips' in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The clips feature has been around for some versions in VS Code. It automatically tracks what code I wrote (or copied?) and then offers these clips on a popup when starting a similar statement (e.g. a return statement):

[image: Clip in VS Code]

However, this feature drives me nuts. There has been no single circumstance where I benefited from it (why would a seasoned programmer repeat parts of his code? Code-reuse, anyone?). However, if I'm typing fast and I'm not careful, I accidentally select it and the whole clip gets pasted.

Is there a way to disable this feature in VS Code? I neither found any corresponding settings [in the official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) nor did any search engine point me in the correct direction.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That must be an extension you have installed.

Comment: You're right! It actually was Clipboard Manager! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting -> Clipboard-manager -> Snippet: Enabled

Uncheck "Enable completion snippets".